# Junit for Apache Kafka Listener with retry Template

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Need guidance on how to write integration JUnit test for Kafka consumer class, to assert how many times the message consume was retried.
I have added a retry template in Kafka configuration.

**Configuration class**

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> listernerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory);
    factory.setRetryTemplate(kafkaRetry());
    return factory;
}
public RetryTemplate kafkaRetry(){
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(2*1000l);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(3);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    return retryTemplate;
}
```

**Consumer class**

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic}", groupId = "${kafka.group-id}",
        containerFactory = "listernerFactory")
public void consume(String messagePayload) {
    logger.info("Consumed message: {}", messagePayload);
}
```

Expecting Junit to

1. send a message to the topic.
2. assert how many times the consumer was invoked.

Note:-  I have tried searching but in most of the cases they are creating a new consumer in test classes to verify instead of invoking the actual consumer class.

Comment: Have you looked at the existing tests for Spring? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/main/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/retrytopic

Comment: Those tests are for a different type of retry (non-blocking retry - https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-topic). For this type of retry, you can add a `RetryListener` to the `RetryTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `RetryTemplate` a `@Bean` and auto wire it into your test.

You can then add a `RetryListener` to the template and assert that the `onError()` method is called the expected number of times.